# Haskell circular definition interrupt

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Hello everyone i came over a curious thing trying to learn circular definition in Haskell. We have these two cases:

```
module Main
where    
  mgood = 1:head (tail (tail mgood)):mgood

  list = take 10 mgood

  main = do

       print list
```

For the code above i get this output [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] which i understand why but the proble is in this code:

```
module Main
where
  mbad = 1:head (tail (tail (tail mbad))):mbad

  list = take 10 mbad

  main = do

       print list
```

Where i get this output [1, {Interrupted!}. Can someone explain me why this happens and what's the difference between the 2 cases?

Comment: Please do not vandalise questions -- even if you happen to have posted them.

Answer (score 9):

Both of your definitions fit the pattern `result = foo : bar : result`. So what we end up with, in both cases, is a circular list that looks like this:

```
foo : bar : foo : bar : foo : bar : ...
```

In both cases `foo` is `1`, so it doesn't depend on anything else. But `bar` does.

In `mgood` you define `bar` to be equal to the third element of the list, so `bar` is equal to `foo`, which is `1`. So both `foo` and `bar` are `1` and that's what you get: an infinite list of `1`s.

In `mbad` you define `bar` to be equal to the *fourth* element. So `bar` is equal to itself. This infinitely recursive definition of `bar` leads to an infinite loop when trying to evaluate `bar`.